# Positive semidefiniteness of the product of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and a nonnegative diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it true that the product of a symmetric PSD matrix and nonnegative diagonal matrix?

For $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $D\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, let $A\succeq O$ and $D:=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\dots,d_n)$, where $d_i\ge0$ for all $i$.
Then, is $AD$ positive semidefinite?

It is known that when two psd matrices $A$ and $B$ are non-commuting, $AB$ is not psd. Although $AD\neq DA$, how about the case where $B$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix?

I found that the hypothesis is true when $n=2$. Given

$$
A:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\ b & c\end{array}\right)\succeq O,\quad D:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}d_1 & 0 \\ 0 & d_2\end{array}\right)\ge O.
$$

Since $A\succeq O$, $a\ge 0$, $c\ge 0$, and $ac-b^2\ge 0$.
The product $AD$ is

$$
AD=\left(\begin{array}{cc}d_1 a & d_2 b \\ d_1 b & d_2 c\end{array}\right).
$$

All the determinants of principal minors for $AD$ are nonnegative because

$$
d_1a\ge0,\ d_2c\ge 0,\ d_1d_2(ac-b^2)\ge 0.
$$

Is this result possible to generalize $n\ge 2$?

Comment: Is $A D$ even symmetric?  If not, then discussing its PSD-ness is kind of silly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this setting it is not true that AD is positive semi-definite. Take the following example:

$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$

and

$
D=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0.01 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$

Then

$
AD=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0.02 & 1\\
0.01 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$

For $AD$ to be positive semi-definite it must be the case that for
any vector $x$, $x^{T}ADx\geq0$. So consider

$
x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
1
\end{array}\right)
$

This gives

$
x^{T}ADx=-1.72
$

The issue is that AD is not symmetric, so showing that all the determinants of principal minors for AD are nonnegative is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for showing a counterexample and pointing out my proof is false.